# Why don't we get reputation points on Meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

This is a weird question but I can't resist. I had to ask. Why don't we receive reputation points when some posts get upvotes in Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: What would be achieved by that? What behavior would you be trying to encourage?

Comment: I just asked why we don't get reputation points. I am not trying to encourage any kind of behaviour.

Comment: One issue is that users tend to use up and down votes on meta to indicate agreement or disagreement...as opposed to "Good" vs. "Bad" question.  Here, for instance, you've got $3$ up votes and $3$ down which, to me, suggests that people are divided on the issue, not that people are split on the quality of your question.

Comment: Much of meta takes place in the comments, which reputation doesn't measure. So "meta rep." would not be a genuine reflection of meta participation (unless it is measured in a different way from "main rep.".

Comment: Also, why the close votes? This seems like a normal, reasonable question to me.

Comment: @lulu But this is different on meta.stackexchange.com right?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi  I don't speak for everyone, but I think that what I am describing is common practice.  Right now, for instance, this question has $6$ upvotes and $5$ down.  Do $5$ people consider it a bad question, worthy of demerit?  But it's a perfectly reasonable question.  I think those $5$ users believe that there should not be reputation attached to posts here and they are indicating their view with their vote.

Comment: @lulu ....I had the question that, meta exchange deducts points for doing so....but it's function is supposed to be the same as any.metaSE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[What is reputation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.

Knowing much about *mathematics* does not equate with knowing much about *Mathematics Stack Exchange*. Of course, these are not mutually exclusive, but they're two different things and we don't add your Physics Stack Exchange reputation to your Mathematics account either (apart from the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232)).

Also, there are some users who are very knowledgeable about mathematics, but have 'unpopular' opinions which tend to get downvoted on Meta. It doesn't make sense to deduct those from their main reputation, does it?

An alternative would be to have everyone start at 1 meta reputation (just like everyone here [starts at 0 badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)) and apply up- and downvotes as they would on the main site. This is how [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) works, but that [has its own problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143251/295232) and some people have asked to abandon that system.

Comment: Meta stackexchange is not related to any corresponding main site so in a way it is different from meta.math.